# implementing my own compareTo() without using apache CompareToBuilder

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have the below class that was using the apache commons compareTo(). I want to replace it with my own implementation in compareTo(). When I did the replacement as outlined below I started getting duplicate keys.

I started getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: ....

I haven't modified the equals or hashcode method in any of the class.

**Is my compareTo() implementation wrong?**

```
class key {

    private final PrimaryKeyInfo keyInfo;
    private final String value;

  // ommitting constructor details
    .............

 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Key key = (Key) o;

        if (keyInfo != null ? !keyInfo.equals(key.keyInfo) : key.keyInfo != null) return false;
        return value != null ? value.equals(key.value) : key.value == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = keyInfo != null ? keyInfo.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (value != null ? value.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

 @Override
    public int compareTo(Key o) {
        return new CompareToBuilder()
                .append(keyInfo, o.keyInfo)
                .append(value, o.value)
                .toComparison();
    }
}

}
```

**//I replaced the above compareTo() method with the below**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Key o) {
    if (this == o){
        return 0;
    }
    if(keyInfo.equals(o.keyInfo)){
        return value.compareTo(o.value);
    } else{
        return keyInfo.compareTo(keyInfo);
    }
}
```

Post this,

**ERROR**

I started getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: ....

Additionally adding the PrimaryKeyInfo class for reference

```
public class PrimaryKeyInfo implements Comparable<PrimaryKeyInfo> {
    private final DataType dataType; //Just a enum of data types
    private final String name;

      // ommitting constructor details
        .............

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        PrimaryKeyInfo that = (PrimaryKeyInfo) o;

        if (dataType != that.dataType) return false;
        return name.equals(that.name);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = dataType.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

 @Override
    public int compareTo(PrimaryKeyInfo o) {
        return new CompareToBuilder()
                .append(dataType, o.dataType)
                .append(name, o.name)
                .toComparison();
    }
}
```

Comment: the compareTo should compare both the value and the key info, not one or the other.

Comment: But i have to return only 1, 0, -1 , so how do I compare both to return this value? can you show me example with two attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple typo:

```
return keyInfo.compareTo(keyInfo);
```

should be:

```
return keyInfo.compareTo(o.keyInfo);
```

Comment: ah, additionally should the order in my compareTo() of attributes match the order it is in equals() method?

Comment: @serah There is no "order" in `equals()`. The concept of an order only exists in `compareTo()`. The result should negative if this object is less than the other object, 0 if equal or positive if this object is greater than the other object. The way you're currently implementing it (i.e. `value.compareTo(o.value)` instead of `o.value.compareTo(value)`) seems correct.

Comment: Additionally i have a List<> that is now a member of my class,  that i want to compareTo() against the List<> of another object. What is the best way to do this? My list is sorted by default, if that helps.

Comment: `List` does not implement `Comparable`, so you probably need to do deep comparison for the elements. Since you used commons-lang, the `CompareToBuilder` has a [method for comparing arrays](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html#append-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-), which can serve as an example to build your own implementation.